# how to get longitude,latitude from the city name android code

Tags: android

I want to convert a text taken from a text field which contains the city name, and I want to convert it to longitude and latitude.

this is what I made:

```
String location=city.getText().toString();
            String inputLine = "";
            String result = "";
            location=location.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            String myUrl="http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+location+"&output=csv";
            try{
             URL url=new URL(myUrl);
             URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection();
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              result=inputLine;
              }
               lat = result.substring(6, result.lastIndexOf(","));
               longi = result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
             }
             catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

            //////////////////////////////////
            if (location=="" ) 
            {           
             latitude=loc.getLatitude();
            longitude=loc.getLongitude();
            }
            else 
            {
                latitude=Double.parseDouble(lat);
                longitude=Double.parseDouble(longi);
            }
```

but the code doesn't take the     else statement

I changed the URL to this:

String myUrl="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location+"&sensor=true";

and this is the result:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Nablus",
               "short_name" : "Nablus",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Nablus",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.22504,
               "lng" : 35.260971
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.2439165,
                  "lng" : 35.2929858
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.20615960000001,
                  "lng" : 35.2289562
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

how could I use latitude and longitude in my code??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an easier way by using the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). It does pretty much the same as the Geocoding API.

```
if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
    try {
        String location = "theNameOfTheLocation";
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> addresses= gc.getFromLocationName(location, 5); // get the found Address Objects

        List<LatLng> ll = new ArrayList<LatLng>(addresses.size()); // A list to save the coordinates if they are available
        for(Address a : addresses){
            if(a.hasLatitude() && a.hasLongitude()){
                ll.add(new LatLng(a.getLatitude(), a.getLongitude()));
            }  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {
         // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a far superior option to the one I provided I think and OP will avoid having to update your code if Google changes the format of the JSON output.

Answer (score 5):

it's too late but for others that have same problem
after 4 days i get **longitude** and **latitude** from the city name

i used

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=tehran&sensor=false
```

where ***"tehran"*** is the city name

by this link you can get a json as below

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Tehran",
               "short_name" : "Tehran",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tehran",
               "short_name" : "Tehran",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tehran Province",
               "short_name" : "Tehran Province",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Iran",
               "short_name" : "IR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.8345498,
                  "lng" : 51.6062163
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5590784,
                  "lng" : 51.0934209
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 35.6891975,
               "lng" : 51.3889736
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.8345498,
                  "lng" : 51.6062163
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5590784,
                  "lng" : 51.0934209
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2dzzH0kAjj8RvCRwVnxps_A",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

so as you can see there are the attribute that we need in "location" object
as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37525989/7858689) said at first we need to get Json from top URL
so easily we add **JsonTask** Class

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // u can use a dialog here
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-) 

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // here "result" is json as stting
    }
}
}
```

to call and save JSON string you need this code

```
JsonTask getRequest = new JsonTask();
String JSONString = getRequest.execute("Url address here").get();
```

then we should get longitude and latitude. so here is s.th that we need

```
JSONObject jsonResponse1;
try {
    jsonResponse1 = new JSONObject(jsonMap1);
    JSONArray cast = jsonResponse1.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < cast.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject name = actor.getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONObject location = name.getJSONObject("location");
        lat1 = location.getString("lat");
        lng1 = location.getString("lng");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

lat1 and lng1 has the values :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the new API you get back a JSON object. Instead of parsing it as a string, parse it as a JSON object. Here is (finally) code that compiles and returns the correct values for the JSON string you gave.

```
try
{
    org.json.JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(result);
    org.json.JSONArray jsa = jso.getJSONArray("results");
    org.json.JSONObject js2 = jsa.getJSONObject(0);
    org.json.JSONObject js3 = js2.getJSONObject("geometry");
    org.json.JSONObject js4 = js3.getJSONObject("location");
    Double lat = (Double)js4.getDouble("lat");
    Double lng = (Double)js4.getDouble("lng");

}
catch(JSONException jse)
{
    jse.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I changed the URL to :

    String myUrl="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location+"&sensor=true";

could you see my question, I edited it

Comment: I now see your edit. See the code I supplied. The JSONObject I got back is different from the one you got, apparently. You can use JSONArray to process the results object.

Comment: As I indicated, I had a different set of data returned. I'll make it work with the set of data you got. But please see @steve 's answer below which is far superior to using the method I supplied.

Answer (score 1):

`android.location.Geocoder` contains a method `getFromLocationName`, which returns a list of Addresses. You can query the address for its lat & long.

Answer (score 1):

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Comment: OP wanted `latitude` and `longitude` from `location name`. Your code gives `location name` from `latitude` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

`public static LatLng getCityLatitude(Context context, String city) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context,context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        LatLng latLng = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(city, 1);
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return latLng;
    }`