# Get JSON Data from URL Using Android?

Tags: android, json, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to get JSON data by parsing login url with username and password. I have tried by using below code but I can't get any responses. Please help me.

I am using HTTP Process and API level 23.

I need to parse my URL and get below Response

```
{
    "response":{
                "Team":"A",
                "Name":"Sonu",
                "Class":"First",
              },
                "Result":"Good",
}
```

Below My code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    TextView tv;
    String ab;
    JSONObject jobj = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        new retrievedata().execute();

    }

    class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://myurlhere.com");

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", jobj.toString());

            try {
                ab = jobj.getString("title");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ab;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String ab){

            tv.setText(ab);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: remove the `","` afer `"First"` and `"Good"` to have a valid json

Answer (score 70):

Easy way to get JSON especially for **Android SDK 23**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnHit;
TextView txtJson;
ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JsonTask().execute("Url address here");
        }
    });


}


private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-) 

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        txtJson.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thx, works perfect. Note that `result` is also an empty string when no network is available.

Comment: This was great!

I am BRAND new to Android, and a couple of things not clear to me at first was you need to import

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

And also wasn't obvious at first that ".execute()" was the method that runs it lol

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is help me so much,, btw, can i sent spesific method, like POST, PUT, etc ?

Answer (score 14):

I feel your frustration.

Android is crazy fragmented, and the the sheer amount of different examples on the web when searching is not helping.

That said, I just completed a sample partly based on mustafasevgi sample,
partly built from several other stackoverflow answers, I try to achieve this functionality, in the most simplistic way possible, I feel this is close to the goal.

(Mind you, code should be easy to read and tweak, so it does not fit your json object perfectly, but should be super easy to edit, to fit any scenario)

```
protected class yourDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params)
    {

        String str="http://your.domain.here/yourSubMethod";
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(str);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            return new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("App", "yourDataTask", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(bufferedReader != null)
            {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response)
    {
        if(response != null)
        {
            try {
                Log.e("App", "Success: " + response.getString("yourJsonElement") );
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.e("App", "Failure", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the json object it is targeted towards.

```
{
    "yourJsonElement":"Hi, I'm a string",
    "anotherElement":"Ohh, why didn't you pick me"
}
```

It is working on my end, hope this is helpful to someone else out there.

Comment: how do I call it for example in my main class

Comment: It's 2021 and this is still relevant. Man do I miss simpler days writing ajax requests. Thank you, now all that is left is to refactor this to something nice and tidy

Answer (score 5):

If you get the server response as a String, without using a third party library you can do

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jsonResponse = json.getJSONObject("response");
String team = jsonResponse.getString("Team");
```

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Otherwise to parse json you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

**EDIT** without libraries (not tested)

```
class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://myurlhere.com");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); //Your method here 
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line + "\n");

            if (buffer.length() == 0)
                return null;

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
            exception = e;
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    exception = e;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response != null) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject jsonResponse = json.getJSONObject("response");
            String team = jsonResponse.getString("Team");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here in this snippet, we will see a volley method, add below dependency in-app level gradle file

1. compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1' -> adding volley dependency.
2. implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' -> adding gson for JSON data manipulation in android.

Dummy URL -> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users (HTTP GET Method Request)

```
public void getdata(){
    Response.Listener<String> response_listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response",response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("address").getJSONObject("geo");
                Log.e("lat",jsonObject.getString("lat");
                Log.e("lng",jsonObject.getString("lng");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    Response.ErrorListener response_error_listener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                //TODO
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                //TODO
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                //TODO
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                //TODO
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    };

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",response_listener,response_error_listener);
    getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}   

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    //requestQueue is used to stack your request and handles your cache.
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

Visit https://github.com/JainaTrivedi/AndroidSnippet-/blob/master/Snippets/VolleyActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about android but in POJ I use

```
public final class MyJSONObject extends JSONObject {
    public MyJSONObject(URL url) throws IOException {
        super(getServerData(url));
    }
    static String getServerData(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String text = ir.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        return (text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works on Android but requires minimum API level 24

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is deprecated in Android Java, so use `Executor` in your Activity.

Take a sample JSON (http://ip-api.com/json) with the contents:

```
{"status":"success","country":"India","countryCode":"IN","region":"GJ","regionName":"Gujarat","city":"Surat","zip":"395007","lat":21.1888,"lon":72.8293,"timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","isp":"Reliance Jio Infocomm Limited","org":"Reliance Jio Infocomm Limited","as":"AS55836 Reliance Jio Infocomm Limited","query":"192.168.1.1"}
```

This in your `Activity`:

```
final LocationItems[] locationItems = {new LocationItems()};
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                final String[] response = new String[1];
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadActivity.this);
                progressDialog.show();
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    // Background work here

                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://ip-api.com/json/").openConnection();
                        response[0] = Utils.convertStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
                        locationItems[0] = new LocationItems();
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response[0]);
                        locationItems[0].city= object.getString("city");
                        locationItems[0].state=object.getString("regionName");
                        locationItems[0].country=object.getString("country");
                        // more string like;

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        locationItems[0].city="Mumbai";
                        locationItems[0].state="Maharashtra";
                        locationItems[0].country="India";
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    handler.post(() -> {
                        // UI Thread work here
                        // return locationItems;
                        Log.e("city", locationItems[0].city);
                        Log.e("state", locationItems[0].state);
                        Log.e("country", locationItems[0].country);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    });
                });
}
```

`LocationItems.java`:

```
public class LocationItems {
    public String city, state, country; // add more if needed
}
```

And here a function to convert to string:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next().replace(",", ",\n") : "";
}
```

Comment: What I didn't get is some value if the Json has more than one level. For example, using your sample file, if `"status":"success"` have another branch like `{"status": {"success":"case 1",},{"failure":"case 2",}}`. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String sResponse;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    s = s.append(sResponse);
}
Gson gson = new Gson();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s.toString());
String link = jsonObject.getString("Result");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class GetProfileRequestAsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (urls.length > 0) {
            String url = urls[0];
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            httpget.setHeader("x-li-format", "json");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                if (response != null) {
                    //If status is OK 200
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        //Convert the string result to a JSON Object
                        return new JSONObject(result);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(data));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fairly short code to read JSON from an URL. (requires Guava due to usage of `CharStreams`).

```java
    private static class VersionTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = null;
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/user_name/repo_name/releases/latest");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                result = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("VersionTask", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                String version = "";
                try {
                    version = new JSONObject(result).optString("tag_name").trim();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("VersionTask", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
                if (version.startsWith("v")) {
                    //process version
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS: This code gets the latest release version (based on tag name) for a given GitHub repo.