# Google Directions API transit returns always “ZERO_RESULTS” when i use a persian word in url

Tags: android, json, google-maps, latitude-longitude

i need to get Longitude and Latitude from city name.
i search and test a lot of source code , but non of them helped me.

till i found this link :[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=تهران&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86&sensor=false)

so i try to get json from this URL
i try [this source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37525989/7858689)

but output just shows **“ZERO_RESULTS”**

as you can see in **first link** i use a persian word : *"تهران"*. If i use "tehran" instead of "تهران" output is correct.

**here is my question: how can i use *persian* word in URL** ?

**UPDATE:**
even i try to decode the address , but it does not help me! :(

Comment: Looks like it works fine for me when I click on that link

Comment: @DanielNugent Yes , the link does not have any problem , but when I try to get json , it returns empty string and ZERO_RESULTS shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem

```
String encodedUrl1 = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");
```

i must encode just city name and after encoded, use it in URL

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodedUrl1 + "&sensor=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call the same request with `language=fa` parameter:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=تهران&sensor=false&language=fa](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86&sensor=false&language=fa)

Comment: thanks for your answer but it shows ZERO_RESULT again