# API works on POSTMAN, statuscode = 200 in android but -1 entity

Tags: android, api, httprequest, httpresponse

Currently reviewing code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229869/get-json-data-from-url-using-android)

Problem is,
the API works on postman
from the Android side, is return statuscode 200
But the entity is always -1.

I wonder where's the problem is...

Comment: The problem is in your code. you have to solve it yourself if you don't post it here

Comment: problem in your code and without seeing your code no body help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question and
probably help others who will encounter the same problem as me.

our local API is inside a proxy. 
So check your emulator proxy settings.

Even your workstation is already configured to the proxy,
your emulator (AVD) may not.

It would still send a response of 200, but no entity since
it is not allowed by the proxy.