# GET method for specific login

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is when user enters email and password I want to check it
and based on success message want to print success, message and hash on Toast.maketext.
My url for login is: https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login
And for testing purpouses email should be equal to a@a.ba and pasword 12345, so when you change the link to: https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login&email=a@a.ba&pw=12345
you get success= 1.

So far I have this code and don't know where to register button, do I do this in onCreate or setOnClickListener or doInBackgroung

```
String data ="";
     String dataParsed = "";
    String singleParsed ="";
   EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   String MAIN_URL = "https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php";
    String LOGIN_URL = "https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login";
    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                String password = passwordText.getEditableText().toString().trim();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Look at `Volley`: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: @Maxouille Already tried, even tried number of tutorials, but it doesn't pass that  a should be equal to login.

Comment: Can you post your code ? What data are you collecting ? I don't understand clearly what's your trying to do.

Comment: @Maxouille if I put this url:"https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php" it is not valid, but this one "view-source:https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login&email=a@a.ba&12345" sends the success message, how can I make login that if email is equal to a@a.ba and pw =12345 programatically depended on some other credentials. Do you understand anything now xD ?

Comment: Post the code you wrote.

Comment: @Maxouille I just posted edited version, can you please take a look ? Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you simply need to parse the response from the server to your Android App. Using your links the data is being generated correctly. Have a look at this answer, it should provide you what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230067/8382028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you got from https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login&email=a@a.ba&pw=12345 is a [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) that looks like this :

```
{
  "success":1,
  "message":"",
  "hash":"askojgfiouw8ursaj"
}
```

From what I understand, you want to check if the user's login credentials are correct by calling the server at the address https://www.digitalis.ba/korisnik2/android-getResult.php?a=login and adding the data as parameters.

To do this, you need a `HTTP POST` request. That's how it should be done. A `HTTP GET` request works to and I'll show you that at the end of the post.

Using the [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) library, you can make HTTP requests easily. Below is the code of your onClickListener:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = emailText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
        
        // Create a JSONObject for adding parameters to the POST Request
        JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
        postparams.put("email", email);
        postparams.put("pw", password);
            
        // Creating the post request object
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, MAIN_URL, postparams,
            new Response.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Success Callback
                    successValue = response.getInt("success");
                    if (successValue == "1") {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Logged in succesfully");
                        // DO YOUR STUFF
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Login failed: Wrong email or password");
                        // DO YOUR OTHER STUFF
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Failure Callback
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error posting request: "+error.toString());
                }
            });

        // Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, "postRequest");       
    }
});
```

With a `HTTP GET` request, it works to but you have to concatenate your URL by yourself:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = emailText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                
        LOGIN_URL = String.format("%s&email=%s&pw=%s", LOGIN_URL, email, password);
          
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOGIN_URL, null, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //Success Callback
                successValue = response.getInt("success");
                if (successValue == "1") {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Logged in succesfully");
                    // DO YOUR STUFF
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Failure Callback
                Log.d("TAG", "Login failed: Wrong email or password");
                // DO YOUR OTHER STUFF
            }
        });

        // Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, "getRequest");
    }
});
```

Hope one of these solutions will work for you :)

Best